# Long calculation times with XLOOKUP vs INDEX-MIN-COLUMN

Tags: arrays, excel, xlookup

I'm using this formula `=IF(B24="","",IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet3!$C$3:$EE$3,,MIN(IF(Sheet3!$C$4:$EE$23=(Sheet2!C24&$K$18),COLUMN(Sheet3!$C:$EE)))-2),"NF"))` to return a cell value in the top row of an array - a date in this case.

The search criteria is a combination of a unique project number and a 2 digit status alphanumerical code for the project. The array consists of 23 rows where combinations of the unique numbers are found, each with different status codes.

So essentially, I'm building a FILTERED project status dashboard that returns dates linked to the relevant project status.

The code above is inspired from ( [LINK](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-find-column-containing-a-value) ) that uses a very similar layout, but it uses town suburbs linked to postal codes instead of project numbers and status codes. The formula works well (though, not entered as an array formula), but I don't have a single formula in the sheet, I have 3 300 occurrences of this formula.

The problem comes in when the user changes the FILTER - Excel recalculates the entire dashboard and that takes anywhere from 2 to 5 minutes to run. You hit the escape button and cancel the calculation after setting the filter, but Excel just starts calculating again after a few seconds. After that, Excel's response is sluggish and almost unusable. Yes - our hardware is pretty weak ...

I tried XLOOKUP as well, but can't set the "lookup_array" to an array ( `Sheet3!$C$4:$EE$23` ) because it doesn't match the "return-array" ( `Sheet3!$C$3:$EE$3` ) Concatenating the lookup arrays with `&` works, but then you'd have to do that for all 23 rows, and again, multiply that by 3 300.

I thought of creating a UDF, but the function will still be called every time Excel recalculates after filtering... 3 300 calls ...

Any ideas on how to make the INDEX version run faster, or make the XLOOKUP accept the lookup_array as `Sheet3!$C$4:$EE$23` in the hopes that it'll run faster?

Thank you!

Comment: If you're open to a UDF, couldn't you just use the `RANGE().FIND` method to locate a match, then grab the column and return the value in the 1st row? It would definitely be faster.

Comment: I haven't tried anything like that yet, do you have an example of an UDF that can do this?

Comment: Not off hand, but it shouldn't be complex. You would have your lookup value and your lookup range as inputs and the `Range.Find()` method in the function would return a value from your top row.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an elegant solution, but it works.

I imported the dataset into a helper sheet, where I combined the cell value with the corresponding value in Column A for each row ( a name in this case ) and the date from row 1 for each column, using underscore as a delimiter.

This new data range was then given a unique name, EE in this case.

On a second helper sheet, using this formula `=INDEX(Filtered,1+INT((ROW('Sheet1'!C3)-1)/COLUMNS(Filtered)),MOD(ROW('Sheet1'!C3)-1+COLUMNS(Filtered),COLUMNS(Filtered))+1)` and drag it down till it returns an REF! error and going back one row before the error.

This transposes all the data into a single column G. Using `=UNIQUE(SORT(FILTER(B3:B3240,B3:B3240<> "","")))`  then gives me a filtered list of unique values in column H that I then run

`=IF(H3="","",LEFT(H3, SEARCH("_",H3,1)-1))` for the first data value in I, and

`=IF(H3="","",MID(H3, SEARCH("_",H3) + 1, SEARCH("_",H3,SEARCH("_",H3)+1) - SEARCH("_",H3) - 1))` for the middle data value in J, and

`=IF(H3="","",IFERROR(TEXT(RIGHT(H3,5),"yyyy-mm-dd"),"NF"))` for the last data value in K.

Then just run XLOOPUP across columns I, J and K.

Runs quick and easy and solves a few of the other issue I had as well.

The second data set has just over 35 000 rows - still works well and fast.